# Building Boost.MPI with Intel MPI

Tags: c++, boost, mpi, boost-mpi, intel-mpi

I'm trying to build Boost.MPI 1.47 with Intel MPI 4.0.0.012, but Boost is not able to find the installation. I've tried various `using mpi ;`-variants in user-config.jam including `using mpi ;`, `using mpi : mpicl ;` and `using mpi : c:/path/to/mpi/mpicl.bat` without luck. I've also tried using the `using mpi : <find-shared-library>impi ;` although I'm not sure what `<find-shared-library>` really do).

Using `using mpi ;` I get:

```
===============MPI Auto-configuration===============
Did not find Microsoft Compute Cluster Pack in C:\Program Files\Microsoft Comput
e Cluster Pack.
warning: toolset mpi initialization: can not find tool mpic++
warning: initialized from c:\temp\boost_1_47_0\tools/build/v2\user-config.jam:94

The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
MPI auto-detection failed: unknown wrapper compiler mpic++
Please report this error to the Boost mailing list: http://www.boost.org
You will need to manually configure MPI support.
warning: toolset mpi initialization: can not find tool mpirun
warning: initialized from c:\temp\boost_1_47_0\tools/build/v2\user-config.jam:94

MPI launcher: mpirun -np
====================================================
```

Using `using mpi : mpicc` I get:

```
===============MPI Auto-configuration===============
warning: toolset mpi initialization:
warning: can not find user-provided command  'mpicl'
warning: initialized from c:\temp\boost_1_47_0\tools/build/v2\user-config.jam:94

The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
The system cannot find the path specified.
MPI auto-detection failed: unknown wrapper compiler mpicl
Please report this error to the Boost mailing list: http://www.boost.org
You will need to manually configure MPI support.
warning: toolset mpi initialization: can not find tool mpirun
warning: initialized from c:\temp\boost_1_47_0\tools/build/v2\user-config.jam:94

MPI launcher: mpirun -np
====================================================
```

`using mpi : <find-shared-library>impi ;` results in

```
MPI auto-detection failed: unknown wrapper compiler <find-shared-library>impi
```

How do I link Boost.MPI with Intel MPI (Windows, Visual Studio 2010, x64)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The troubles was caused by a missing : in the `using`-statment. Boost.MPI compiled fine after correcting this to `using mpi : : <find-shared-library>impi ;` (notice that there are two ':').